# Get last absolute end time for time series in KairosDB

Tags: rest, timestamp, time-series, kairosdb

I'm looking for a way to get the last absolute end time for a time series stored in KairosDB. Is there a way to get this with the REST API?

Many thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kairosdb-group/limit/kairosdb-group/lqJzm_o7ovM/pqE8BgEdNtIJ

To get the last absolute end time, you can query data from 1st Jan 1970 and add "limit":1 and "order":"desc" in your query.

Cheers,
Greg